# Understanding the monadicity of groupoids over splittings

Tags: category-theory, groupoids, monads

In the paper [*The shift functor and the comprehensive factorization for internal groupoids*](http://www.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1987__28_3_197_0) by Bourn, the author proves that for a fixed finitely complete category, the category of internal groupoids is monadic over the category of points. The latter is the category whose objects are split epis equipped with a section, and whose arrows are serially commutative squares between such pairs.

The author notes this result is unexpected to him on page 2.

I am only able to follow parts of the proof and feel I am missing the big picture entirely. It just feels like black magic.

1. How to think of this result? What is some intuition for it?
2. What are the idea behind the proof?

Comment: I'd guess there's a significant risk nobody here has heard of this result. The category of points is central to a lot of Bourn and friends' work since, though, so you might be able to find a friendlier treatment in some newer reference.